# Prove that this is a lattice in $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $A$ be a subset of $C[a,b]$ such that for all $$f,g\in A,c\in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow cf,c+f,\max(f,g)\in A.$$
>   Prove that this is a lattice whose order defined by: $f\leq g $ if for all $x$ in$[a,b]:f(x)\leq g(x)$.

I've tried: $\min(f,g)=f+g-\max(f,g)$, but since A is not necessarily closed under addition, though RHS are all in A, this might not hold.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck and in what context you have encountered the problem, i.e edit your post with this information
, so that someone can help you. Just stating 
a question like this then it is likely it will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is given by $$\min(f,g)=-1\cdot\max(-1\cdot f,-1\cdot g)$$which is valid since $-1\in\Bbb R$.